# How magmi import prices when in Magento price attribute is set to website

Tags: magento, magmi

I changed the scope of the Magento price attribute to Website in order to have different prices for different websites.
As I try to update products from magmi, magmi doesn't update the prices for the websites but only the default price so the prices of all websites and storeview are always the default Website/Storeview price.

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484202/importing-prices-for-multiple-store-views-using-magmi/47294075

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [store column](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Behaviour_-_store_column) for this. Then just create a CSV with the columns store, sku and price like this:

```
store; sku; price
store_code_1; SKU_001; 10
store_code_2; SKU_001, 55
store_code_1; SKU_002; 20
store_code_2; SKU_002, 110
...
```

Comment: this is what I've done but only for the price attribute it's not working. Works for all other attributes but for the price attribute not.

Comment: then I think the problem might be in a compatibility of your Magento version and Magmi version. What version of Magento and Magmi do you use?

Comment: 1.8.1 Magento. 0.7.18 Magmi

Comment: What it does is setting always the default price and not changing the price for the website

Comment: Prices per website, not for store view, how ever, after importing with website attribute it mess products assigning to webstore...

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, first you need make a `CSV` file with top cells:

`sku, _store, price`

Then fill date for expl:

```
0001, uk, 0.99
    , de, 0.89

    , uk, 0.99

    , de, 0.77
```

ETC. After we make the `CSV`, just import with standard magento importer.

The price scope is per website, I really don't know why it works when importing per store.

I tried do it with ~400 products on more than 10 store views, and it works.