# Importing prices for multiple store views using Magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

I am trying to update prices using Magmi on 2 store views but I am having issues. Here is my setup.

Website Name (Code: bab)
Store Name (Root Category: BAB)

Has 2 store views
Storeview 1 (Code: abc)
Storeview 2 (Code: bab)

As I am just wanting to update prices for the storeviews my csv file is as follows:
store, websites, sku, price
admin, faf, 1001, 5.00
admin, gpf, 1001, 7.00

Unfortunately the prices are just not updating as needed. Only 1 store price updates, while the other one doesn't.

I have tried importing in different ways.

1. I imported the prices as 2 separate csv files, 1 for each store view.
2. I imported both store prices in one csv file. With all products for 1st store at top of csv. Then the 2nd block of products after the 1st store products.
3. I also tried a csv in the above format where there are 2 rows for each sku with the store view specified on each row.
4. I also tried adding a 3rd row with admin, website (left blank), sku, price. To account for a default value. In case a default value was needed to be specified also. I tried adding the default row, before both storeviews and also as the 3rd row, after both storeviews.

None of these approaches are applying the price to both. I either get just 1 price update. Or I get the default price show in 1 store, and the other store not updating at all.

I have also been re-indexing after each magmi import, clearing magento cache and my chrome cache.

I have also checked to make sure there are no discounts or pricing rules effecting any products.

So I am hoping someone can advise me on anything I am doing wrong or anything else I need to check. Maybe I am configuring my csv file wrong?

Nore: I have over 5000 products and I don't think I can use magneto's default import feature / data profiles as it is really slow and often just crashes.

Thanks and hope you can help. Would be much appreciated.
Paul

Comment: Interesting that you say you can't use the default import profiles, as I recently read a comparison that put the dataflow profiles as the best performers across the board (assuming your indexers are configured correctly). All Magmi does differently is avoid the indexers by using direct SQL. Anyway - the question - what scope is your price attribute set for? Website? Have you tried using the website code instead of the store code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

as stated in magmi support : http://sourceforge.net/p/magmi/support-requests/121/#9fbb

to work with multistore, you MUST vary on "store" column putting storeviews code, not on "websites" column.
here:

```
store,sku, price
abc, 1001, 5.00
bab, 1001, 7.00
```

This should fix your problem

Comment: Please don't link to external site unless it is there to support the content you've already put in your answer. Answers should stand alone if the link ever dies.

Comment: In fact, the initial requestor asked the exact same question on magmi support forum, i just wanted to avoid content duplication. edited my response with content

Comment: Stack Overflow works on the premise that no other site exists - so if the answer isn't on here then there isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open magmi/engines/magmi_productimportengine.php and add this condition

```
if ($attrcode == "price" && $attrdesc["is_configurable"] == 1){
            $scope=0;   
            }
```

After

```
if ($attrcode != "price" && $attrdesc["is_configurable"] == 1)
            {
                $scope = 0;
            }
```

https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/issues/435